# pip не является внешней или внутренней командой / не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-faq

Когда я пытаюсь установить модуль, выдает: "pip не является внешней или внутренней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Я прокладывал полный путь. Установщик пакетов, вроде, не нужно устанавливать отдельно. Windows 7.

Comment: Да просто инсталлятор не прописал путь в PATH

Answer (score 12):

Вам нужно установить путь к `pip` в переменные окружения, это можно сделать при установке `python` выбрав пункт `Add Python to PATH.`

Если вы уже установили, но забыли выбрать этот пункт, можно добавить путь вручную:

```
Панель управления -> Система -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Переменные среды
```

Вы увидите 2 окошка, `Переменные среды пользователя для <username>` и `Системные переменные`, вам нужно первое, нажимаем на переменную `Path -> Изменить`, далее вы увидите поле `Значение переменной`, в конец поставьте разделитель `;` и добавьте путь к директории где находится `pip` (например, `C:\Python\Scripts`, путь к директории Python может отличаться).

Answer (score 4):

При установке **Python** вам необходимо установить **pip** и, возможно, отметить **Add Python to PATH**.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй так:

```
python3 -m pip -V
```

Если вернёт версию, то устанавливать можно так

```
python3 -m pip install pip
```

Рекомендую использовать совместно с `Virtual Environment`

Answer (score 0):

Это сообщение означает, что система не может найти файл pip, который вы пытаетесь запустить. Возможно, у вас не установлен Python или переменная среды PATH не содержит директорию, в которой находится установленный Python.

Чтобы установить Python, перейдите на сайт https://www.python.org/ и скачайте и установите самую последнюю версию. Убедитесь, что установка добавит Python в переменную среды PATH.

После установки Python вы должны быть в состоянии запускать pip, чтобы устанавливать модули. Например, чтобы установить модуль requests, выполните следующую команду:

```
pip install requests
```

Если у вас возникают проблемы с установкой модулей с помощью pip, попробуйте выполнить команду pip install -U pip, чтобы обновить версию pip до самой последней.

Answer (score -1):

найдите установщик, нажмите delete или чтото вроде того, потом еще раз запустите установщик и в левом нижнем углу выберите Add Python to PATH, и все

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от [данного ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624624/217579)?