# Говорит, что pip не является командой

Tags: python, pip

[image]

```
pip install vk_api
```

> "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: `pip3 install vk_api` / `python3 -m pip install vk_api`

Comment: Ответ тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624272/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-pip-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: А для питона 2:`python -m pip install vk_api`

Answer (score 0):

Сам сталкивался с такой ошибкой. Эта ошибка возникает скорее всего из-за того, что pip не прописан в path. Попробуйте либо добавить pip в path, либо через cmd, зайдя в папку с питоном, а конкретно в папку Scripts (где лежит pip.exe), попробовать установить пакет.

Т.е. в cmd:

```
cd .../Python37/Scripts
pip install vk_api
```

P.s. этот способ не для виртуального окружения, но думаю, с ним можно сделать что-то подобное.