# Что делать, если не скачиваеться модуль

Tags: python-3.x

Когда я хочу установить , например, colorama, то мне выдаёт СИНТАКТИЧЕСКУЮ ошибку.Когда я вбиваю в консоль pip freeze, то пишет тоже самое.
Второй день уже не могу решить, в чём дело. Если кто знает, пожалуйста, напишите!!!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, эту ошибку в вопрос. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Также было бы хорошо уточнить ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что выдается синтаксическая ошибка, а консоль ОС как правило синтаксических ошибок не выдает, вы не туда вводите.

Нужно вводить в командную строку ОС, а не питона.

Comment: Спасибо, я, как оказалось, вводил не туда! Но когда я хочу скачать pip colorama, то пишет   -   "pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Что делать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624272