# Как установить модуль prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

Запускаю cmd - Enter - pip install -  -U prettytable.
Получаю: «pip» не является исполняемой командой

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624272/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-pip-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Попробуйте `python -m pip install ...`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не установлен сам pip для Python через который вы скачиваете модуль. Для его установки вы можете переустановить язык поставив в инсталляторе галочку на Add to Patch или Pip.

Comment: а где она там эта галочка?

Comment: В установщиках последних версий языка этот пункт размещен в самом низу окна установки и появляется сразу при запуске инсталлятора.
А в установщиках некоторых других версий языка эта галочка появляется при выборе Модифицированного типа установки `Modify`.