# Не получается импортировать Pygame

Tags: pycharm, pygame, pip

Хочу импортировать Pygame, но выходит такая ошибка:

```
pip install pygame
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pip install pygame
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [pip не является внешней или внутренней командой / не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624272/178576)

Comment: скорее всего у вас не установлен пакет pip. Вы писали в cmd pip install? Если да то пакет не установлен, как устанавливать найдите на ютубе там много видео