# Не работает pip

Tags: pip

Выдаёт ошибку

```
"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Что делать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат:[pip не является внешней или внутренней командой / не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624272/pip-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5)

Comment: Чтобы никогда не встречать подобную ошибку и получить навык, который пригодится в разработке на python ВСЕГДА, используйет виртуальные пространства. Почитать можно здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304. Не забывайте ставить "голос за" на те вопросы и ответы, которые вам помогли

Answer (score 5):

Вы должны открыть панель управления, сделать маленькие или большие значки и открыть вкладку `система`. Затем `дополнительные параметры системы` -> `параметры среды`. Во вкладке `переменные среды пользователя...` нужно найти (или создать) переменную `path`. И нажать `изменить`, после чего `создать`. И вводите туда путь до вашего pip. У меня он примерно такой: `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts`

Comment: А зачем вы дизлайкаете вопрос? Он же нормальный - участник прикрепил конкретную ошибку, достаточно описал проблему. Если вопрос не дубликат, его полезно оставить и другим новичкам.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher не воспользовался поиском, скорей всего (моих минусов нет). Вопрос разорбран в нескольких вариантах на ресурсе

Comment: @https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12181/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b

Если он дубликат, можно пометить как дубликат, а не ставить дизы молча, без объяснения причин

Comment: @SpaceResearcher я просто предположил, логику сообщества я давно не изучаю и не пытаюсь понимать.