# Установка модуля pip

Tags: python-3.x

Версия питон 3.3.2. При вызове команды pip install в командной строке ОС пишет, что "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемый программой или пакетным файлом. На других версиях питон так же. Что делать?

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D+pip+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: Для 3.3 все очень плохо: pip нет в стандартной поставке (он появился начиная с 3.4), и get-pip.py требует минимальную версию python 3.7. Я рекомендую перейти на 3.4 как минимум (не представляю, зачем могла понадобиться такая древность как 3.3)

Comment: "На других версиях питон так же" - нет, на более новых версиях Python не так же: pip идет в стандартной поставке, и его в крайнем случае нужно будет просто добавить в переменную окружения PATH, это делается одной галочкой при установке Python, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827099/1365

Comment: * Почему 3.4 рекомендую - потому что это последняя версия Python, поддерживающая Windows XP, мой хрустальный шар подсказывает, что вероятно у вас какая-то такая ситуация (иначе не понятно, зачем пытаться устанавливать какие-то древние версии). Более старые версии из ветки 3 смысла ставить нет.

Comment: Я думаю, что да. Перепробовал разные версии Python. Книга по которой учусь видать древняя))

Comment: Просто берите python 3.10 или python 3.11.

Comment: Нет. Я посмотрел. У меня Windows 7 максимальная.

Comment: Попробую новую версию python. Спасибо за помощь